# SqlException was unhandled by user code, incorrect syntax near keyword transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Transaction
/// </summary>
public class Transaction
{
    private string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["airmazin"].ConnectionString;
    private string _TransactionID;
    private string _OfferId;
    private string _UserName;
    private string _Image;
    private string _ProductName;
    private decimal _ProductPrice;

    public Transaction()
    {
        this.TransactionID = null;
        this.OfferId = null;
        this.UserName = null;
        this.Image = null;
        this.ProductName = null;
        this.ProductPrice = 0;
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public Transaction(string p_TransactionID, string p_OfferId, string p_UserName, string p_Image, string p_ProductName, decimal p_ProductPrice)
    {
        this.TransactionID = p_TransactionID;
        this.OfferId = p_OfferId;
        this.UserName = p_UserName;
        this.Image = p_Image;
        this.ProductName = p_ProductName;
        this.ProductPrice = p_ProductPrice;
    }

    private string TransactionID
    {
        get { return _TransactionID; }
        set { _TransactionID = value; }
    }
    private string OfferId
    {
        get { return _OfferId; }
        set { _OfferId = value; }
    }
    private string UserName
    {
        get { return _UserName; }
        set { _UserName = value; }
    }
    private string Image
    {
        get { return _Image; }
        set { _Image = value; }
    }
    private string ProductName
    {
        get { return _TransactionID; }
        set { _ProductName = value; }
    }
    private decimal ProductPrice
    {
        get { return _ProductPrice; }
        set { _ProductPrice = value; }
    }  //getter and setter
    public Transaction getProductTransaction(string p_UserName)
    {
        Transaction prodDetail = null;
        string tran_ID, offer_ID, user, Prod_Image, prod_Name;
        decimal prod_Price;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE UserName = @user";
       // think the naming convention is wrong 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", p_UserName);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            tran_ID = dr["TransactionID"].ToString();
            offer_ID = dr["OfferId"].ToString();
            user = dr["UserName"].ToString();
            Prod_Image = dr["Image"].ToString();
            prod_Name = dr["ProductName"].ToString();
            prod_Price = decimal.Parse(dr["ProductPrice"].ToString());
            prodDetail = new Transaction(tran_ID, offer_ID, user, Prod_Image, prod_Name, prod_Price);
        }
        else
        {
            prodDetail = null;
        }
        conn.Close();
        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();
        return prodDetail;

    }
```

not really sure for sql. Just started programming and is currently a student. Met with this error that says near keyword Transaction. Probably the naming coonvention is wrong and might need some help. Want to display transaction history at the aspx page so i am doing the getProductTransaction(){} method but it seems to be having problem

**Edit (from comments)**

And now i want it to display list of transactions instead of a single transaction

Comment: `Transaction` is a mysql reserved keyword. You would need to escape it if you want to use it as a table name.

Comment: @Jonathan, i am still having error, i changed this to  public TransactionDetail getProductTransaction(string p_UserName)

Comment: @Jonathan how did MySQL get into it? This seems to be SQL Server as in SqlCommand etc.

Comment: sorry how do u return a list of transactions in getProduct() method @Jonathan

Comment: @Mary   protected void bind()
    {
        Session["name"] = "John";
        string name = Session["name"].ToString();
        List<TransactionDetail> transList = new List<TransactionDetail>();
        transList.Add(aTrans.getProductTransaction(name));

        gv_Transaction.DataSource = transList;
        gv_Transaction.DataBind();
    }

Comment: i passed it to getProductTransaction(){} which is basically getProduct(){} i changed the name awhile ago

Comment: You have made all your properties private which could be a problem outside your class where you will not be able to access them. You are returning a Transaction from getProductTransaction function but you will not be able to get at the properties.

Comment: i chsnged it to public alr @Mary

Comment: But now i wanted it to display list of transactions instead of a single transaction @Mary

Comment: How many records do you expect your query to return? Is there just 1 per user or can there be many?

Comment: can be many @Mary

Answer (score 3):

Problem may occur because of the table name "Transaction" is a keyword.
you can try this as the query:

```
string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM [Transaction] WHERE UserName = @user";
```

Answer (score 1):

Comments and explanations are inline. The `using` blocks ensure that your `IDisposable` objects are closed and disposed of properly, even it there is an error.

```
public class Transaction
    {
        private string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["airmazin"].ConnectionString;
        public Transaction() { }
        //Auto-Implemented Properties in C# 3 and later
        //The standard get and set are written for you by the compiler
        //Also the compiler writes the private fields where the data is stored
        public string TransactionID { get; set; }
        public string OfferId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
        //changed the function to return a list
        public List<Transaction> getProductTransaction(string p_UserName)
        {
            List<Transaction> lst = new List<Transaction>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            { 
                string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM [Transaction] WHERE UserName = @user";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn))
                { 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", p_UserName);
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    { 

                        if (dr.HasRows)
                            while (dr.Read())
                                //This loop keeps adding records to the list as long as there are records to read
                            {
                                Transaction prodDetail = new Transaction();
                                prodDetail.TransactionID= dr["TransactionID"].ToString();
                                prodDetail.OfferId = dr["OfferId"].ToString();
                                prodDetail.UserName = dr["UserName"].ToString();
                                prodDetail.Image = dr["Image"].ToString();
                                prodDetail.ProductName = dr["ProductName"].ToString();
                                prodDetail.ProductPrice = decimal.Parse(dr["ProductPrice"].ToString());
                                lst.Add(prodDetail);
                            }
                        else
                        {
                            lst = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return lst;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know the OP returns null if there are no rows (replicated here), but that was for a method which only returned zero or one row. I would be steering them away from that design for a method which returns a collection, as it complicates this code and the calling code. If there are no rows, simply return an empty collection.

Comment: Oh, and one last thing...[can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @Richardissimo I agree entirely with the .AddWithValue ban but I didn't want to throw too much at once and I guess I am so happy when someone will use parameters at all that I try to stay cool. I always worry when I see columns with ID names that are strings.

Comment: @Richardissimo I was also leery of null return but I wanted to keep as much of the OP's code in tact as possible so he could still recognize it. I am hoping this is a school project, not a real application.

Comment: No problem, I'm hoping @WenXIANG1999 gets that from my comments. It doesn't help that the OP's code shifted significantly during the comments from returning zero or one in the code for the question, to zero to many; and that's the point where that shift should occur.

Comment: @Richardissimo If I have you to thank for the upvote, it is a special thank you because it put me over 2,000 reps. :-)

Comment: No problem. Congratulations. I almost commented on that since I recently passed that milestone myself.